# Maximum frequency value for word

Tags: python, algorithm

**Seeking help on Homework**

I am given a list and asked to find the most occurring value in a list and returns the amount of times it is occurred. This question is fairly big and i have managed to get through the other parts by myself but this one stumped me.I should add that this is for an assignment any guidance would be appreciated.

**Question Statement : Maximum (word) Frequency**

For example in a book with the following words `['big', 'big', 'bat', 'bob', 'book']` the maximum frequency is 2, i.e., big is the most frequently occurring word, therefore 2 is the maximum frequency.

```
def maximum_frequency(new_list):

    word_counter = {}

    for word in new_list:

        if word in word_counter:

            word_counter[word] += 1

        else:

            word_counter[word] = 1
```

I have gotten this far but I am not sure if its right/where to go from here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As noted in one of your comments, I recommend you tag this question as Homework! And make sure to mention that you're asking for guidance, not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(['big', 'big', 'bat', 'bob', 'book'])
max(c.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

the `max` will returns the most one by its count, you can do:

```
key,rate = max(c.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

the `key` will be `big` and the `rate` will be `2`.

also, you can access all of the items count by `c.items()`. and the output will be

```
{'big': 2, 'bat': 1, 'bob': 1, 'book': 1}
```

Edit:

as  schwobaseggl said the best practice to find from a counter is to use `most_common`.

```
c.most_common(1)[0]
```

Comment: Im not currently allowed to use the import counter method was there any other way?

Comment: Do not use `max` with a `Counter`! `c.most_common(1)` is the way to do this.

Comment: Yeah it is homework but i did try it and pasted my code im just stuck on what to do next.

Comment: It's generally good practice to mention that it's an assignment of some kind so answers can be tailored more towards guidance rather than direct code samples. I mean, if we gave you the answer you didn't learn anything -- right?

Comment: Oh im sorry im new to this website so dont really know how things work. Ill make sure to edit it in now.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like this is some kind of challenge and/or homework you're supposed to be working on, instead of directly providing a code sample let me give you some concepts.

First off, the best way to know if you've seen a word or not is to use a map, in Python -- the term is "dict" and the syntax is simple `{}`, you can store values like this: `my_dict['value'] = true` or whatever key/value you need.

So if you're going to read your words, one by one, and store them into this dict, the what should the value be? You know you want to know the *maximum frequency*, right? Well, so let's use that as our value. By default, if we add a word, we should make sure to set it's initial value to `1` (we've seen it *once*). And if we see a word a second time, we then increment our frequency.

Now that you have a dict full of words and their frequencies, perhaps you might be able to figure out how to find the one with the largest frequency?

So that being said, things you should look into are:

- How to determine if a key exists in a dict
- How to modify the value of a key in a dict
- How to iterate a dict's key/value pairs

After that, your answer should be pretty easy to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to count the occurrence of all the unique elements and compare the frequency with the previously computed frequency.

sample is a list of words.

```
def maxfreq(sample):
    m=0
    frequency=0
    word=''
    set_sample=list(set(sample))
    for i in range(len(set_sample)):
        c=sample.count(set_sample[i])
        if c>m:
            m=c
            frequency=m
            word=set_sample[i]
    return (frequency,word)
```

Comment: This is a homework assignment and you've just given the answer away!

Comment: Will take care of this in future.@BrandonBuck

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
>>> MyList = ["above", "big", "above", "cat", "cat", "above", "cat"]
>>> my_dict = {i:MyList.count(i) for i in MyList}
>>> my_dict
{'above': 3, 'big': 1, 'cat': 3}
```

It can also be accomplish using `collections.Counter` which is compatible with Python 2.7 or 3.x !

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> MyList  = ['big', 'big', 'bat', 'bob', 'book']
>>> dict(Counter(MyList))
{'big': 2, 'bat': 1, 'bob': 1, 'book': 1}
```

If you are open to `Pandas` then it can be done as follows:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series(MyList).value_counts()
big     2
book    1
bob     1
bat     1
dtype: int64
```

@Answer to the OP's next Question in the comment section `what if i wanted to get just the maximum value instead of the word` .

```
>>> pd.Series(MyList).value_counts().max()
2
```

Comment: This is a homework assignment, and you've just given the answer away!

Comment: @BrandonBuck, agreed on your point but Just placed the answer considering as a newbie , next time will keep in mind :D

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def maximum_frequency(new_list):
    word_counter = {}
    for word in new_list:
        if word in word_counter:
            word_counter[word] += 1
        else:
            word_counter[word] = 1

    max_freq = max(word_counter.items(), key=(lambda x: x[1]))
    return max_freq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_data = ['big', 'big', 'bat', 'bob', 'book']
    print(maximum_frequency(test_data))
```

Output:

```
('big', 2)
```

Works fine with Python 2 and 3 and returns result as a tuple of most frequent word and occurrences count.

EDIT:

If you don't care at all which word has the highest count and you want only the frequency number you can simplify it a bit to:

```
def maximum_frequency(new_list):
    word_counter = {}
    for word in new_list:
       if word in word_counter:
            word_counter[word] += 1
        else:
            word_counter[word] = 1

    return max(word_counter.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_data = ['big', 'big', 'bat', 'bob', 'book']
    print(maximum_frequency(test_data))
```

Comment: what if i wanted to get just the maximum value instead of the word

Comment: @NishanthRodricks, see my answer illustrated with `pandas` .

Comment: You could just `return max_freq[1]` to get the second value of the tuple.

Comment: @NishanthRodricks or if you don't care which word has the highest frequency you can use the second solution which I just added.