# Using for loop, how do I get the highest mark and display in python?

Tags: python

I'm supposed to read in a csv file, and create a function that when called, will display the top scorer for a specific module. My current function is:

```
def top_score():
import csv
filePath = "data.csv"
with open(filePath) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)    
    for row in reader:
        top110=max(row["mod1"])
        top121=max(row["mod2"])
        top135=max(row["mod3"])
        top142=max(row["mod4"])
    print("===============================================")
    print("Display Modules Top Scorer")
    print("===============================================")
    print("Module  | First Name | Last Name")
    print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod1",top110(row["first_name"]),top110(row["last_name"])))
    print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod2",row["first_name"],row["last_name"]))
    print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod3",row["first_name"],row["last_name"]))
    print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod4",row["first_name"],row["last_name"]))
```

The CSV contains the following:

```
first_name,last_name,student_id,mod1,mod2,mod3,mod4
Kevin,James,S142D,89,67,54,78
Alex,Keys,S76H,87,78,86,67
Felicia,Lee,S852I,54,78,65,54
```

I get an error saying:

```
line 70, in top_score
print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("CSIT110",top110(row["first_name"]),top110(row["last_name"])))

builtins.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I know I'm doing something stupid, so a lil help would be nice!

Comment: generally wouldn't recommend to import modules inside of functions, but I'm fairly new too

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos - although not necessary here, importing within functions is fine and can improve readability of some code.

Comment: Thanks Craig I'll keep that in mind

Comment: ` print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod1",top110(row["first_name"]),top110(row["last_name"])))` no comma separators between `top110` and `(row)`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire error traceback (formatted as code). This will show which line of your code is causing the error.

Comment: @Craig added the full error!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905195/python-csv-find-max-and-print-the-information or at least the same homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `top110` is obtained from the "maximum" value among columns of each row, which is a string, and is overridden for each iteration. By using an expression of `top110(row["first_name"])` you're treating `top110` as a function when it is a string, hence the error.

If you want to obtain the top scorer of each module, you should use the `max` function on all rows with `operator.itemgetter` as they key function to specify the column you want the maximum value to be based on:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
def top_score():
    filePath = "data.csv"
    with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        rows = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
        top110=max(rows, key=itemgetter('mod1'))        
        top121=max(rows, key=itemgetter('mod2'))        
        top135=max(rows, key=itemgetter('mod3'))        
        top142=max(rows, key=itemgetter('mod4'))        
        print("===============================================")
        print("Display Modules Top Scorer")
        print("===============================================")
        print("Module  | First Name | Last Name")
        print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod1",top110["first_name"],top110["last_name"]))
        print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod1",top121["first_name"],top121["last_name"]))
        print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod1",top135["first_name"],top135["last_name"]))
        print("{0:<8}|{1:>11} | {2:<10}".format("mod1",top142["first_name"],top142["last_name"]))
```

Comment: This code works, but I have no idea why it works. My tutor hasn't taught us about itemgetter,so this seems very confusing. Would it be okay if you explained it a bit for me?

Comment: [`itemgetter('mod1')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is equivalent to `lambda x: x['mod1']`. It returns a function that takes a parameter and returns the value of the parameter with the given key. When `max` iterates through `rows` it uses the key function on each item in `rows` to determine the value of the item and from that, the maximum value among all the items in `rows`.

Answer (score 0):

When you read in data it will be read in as a string. You have to convert it to whatever you need, such as an int.

It's the same with inputs.

So put `int()` around whatever you need to do comparisons against.

The error is because you are attempting to do some type of comparison that does not exist for string objects.

Also for future reference, I would recommend Pandas for handling csv.

Comment: Not allowed to use Pandas for this, sadly. However, when I use max(int(row["mod1"])), I get an error saying: 'int' object is not iterable